# Вопрос по аутентификации в Spring Security

Tags: безопасность, spring-security, grails

Имею, скажем, примерно такой вот код.

```
  class SomeController {
    @Secured(["hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER') and isFullyAuthenticated()"])
        def someAction() {
        User user = springSecurityService.getCurrentUser()
        if (user && user.role.authority in ['ROLE_USER']) {
            //некий код
        } else {
           render status.FORBIDDEN
           return
        }
     }
  }
```

Я просто еще совсем молод в этом направлении и у меня закрались сомнения. Достаточно ли будет одной аннотации или проверки пользователя в теле действия, или желательны оба варианта сразу. Или же проверка пользователя в данном случае избыточна и код можно можно сделать более красивым и удобочитаемым? Как правильно и где золотая середина?
PS: фреймворк `Grails`, язык `Groovy`, но не думаю, что это важно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует досточно много способов, однако я использую два:

**Первый способ.** это добавить в Config.groovy информацию о списке пользователей которым доступен controller:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    ...
    '/some/**'               : ['ROLE_USER'],
]
```

или для конкретного action :

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.interceptUrlMap = [
    ...
    '/some/someAction'            : ['ROLE_USER'],
]
```

**Второй способ.** аннотации *
*Вообще ваша аннотация избыточна, так как пользователь c ролью ('ROLE_USER') уже будет авторизированным, так что проверяем пользователя на наличие этой роли*

```
 class SomeController {
@Secured(["hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')"])
    def someAction() {
      code
    }
}
```

Первым способом я добавляю весь контроллер конкретной группе юзеров, второй способ когда нужно для одного пользователя.

Comment: *Первым способом я добавляю весь контроллер конкретной группе юзеров, вторым способом добавляю один метод*(action) определенной группе пользователей.